# Compare and add a result of comparation in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have been given a task where I have to compare 2 worksheets in a single .xls file. In those 2 worksheets there are the same data only in different order and with different additional infirmation, but what I want to compare is the same. After comparing every row of those 2 worksheets I have to add/type "Matched" or "Not matched" at the end of every row (if one row matches or is stated in the other worksheet and vice-versa). There are hundreds and hundreds of rows, so it would take me a lifetime to do it just by comparing it with my eyes, so I was wondering if there is a way to simplify this task.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sort and then compare??

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you @DavidPostill, I am aware of that, I was just hoping that I might ask if someone has already dealt with such a scenario. I was expecting just a thought that I could later work with or try to use, not a script that would completely do this for me.

Comment: I am not totally clear on what you are doing, but many tasks similar to this one can be accomplished by sorting your data and/or using the match function (e.g. - if you have a column that should have exact matches between the two files, you could `=match(A1,column_A_From_the_Other_File,0)`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your efforts to help me out. I accomplished this task by simply sorting it alphabetically and then compared it with my eyes which took me about 6 hours of work. But it's done now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Ever used **CMD**?

It's powerful once you get the hang of it.

1. Export your two sets of data to a text file: eg a.txt, b.txt, to
   your desktop.
2. Then on the Desktop, SHIFT+Right-Click, select Open command window
   here.
3. Then in your command prompt enter the argument: diff a.txt b.txt >
   results.txt.

This is asking the difference between two text files, print it to a text file named results.

[image]